# Displaying div when selecting certain area, then hiding div when clicking body jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my navigation I have a div. Selecting this div allows another div to appear with options. I would like for the user to be able to select outside of the div and that would close the div, as well as selecting the div that opened it, and the user can obviously re-open this. Think of it as the Facebook navigation dropdown. Just trying to replicate that behavior.

HTML

```
<div class="headRight">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="settings"><div id="here">Account Settings</div></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="navi">
 <ul>
   <li><a><span>Signout</span></a> 
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#here{
    background-image: url(image.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 10px;background-position: 4px 5px;opacity: 1;display: inline-block;height: 15px;overflow: hidden;text-indent: 534px;white-space: nowrap;width: 20px;top: 2px;left: 12px;margin-left: -9px;position: relative;
}
#here.active{
    background-image: url(someimeage.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 10px;background-position: 4px 5px;opacity: 1;display: inline-block;height: 15px;overflow: hidden;text-indent: 534px;white-space: nowrap;width: 20px;top: 2px;left: 12px;margin-left: -9px;position: relative;
}
.navi{
    background: white;width: 200px;box-shadow:0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);height: 122px;float: right;left: 759px;top: 45px;position: absolute; display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$j("#settings").click(function(e){
              if($j("#here").hasClass("active")){
                $j("#here").removeClass("active")
                $j(".navi").hide();
              }
              else{
                $j("#here").addClass("active")
                $j(".navi").show();
              }
            });
            $j(document).click(function(e) {
              if (e.target.className !== "navi" && !$j(".navi").find(e.target).length && $j('.navi').css('display') == 'block') {
                $j(".navi").hide();
              }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add click listeners to the said div and the body

```js
$("#first").click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $("#second").show();
});

$("body").click(function (e) {
 $("#second").hide();
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="first" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 3px solid black">

</div>
<div id="second" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 3px solid black; display: none">

</div>
```

However, this one uses `event.stopPropagation`. If for some reason you don't want to stop propagation because it's nested inside another element that you want to receive events then you can check where the event was called instead and check if it was body or something else.

```js
$("#first").click(function (e) {
 $("#second").show();
});

$("body").click(function (e) {
 console.log(event.target.nodeName);
 if (event.target.nodeName != "BODY")
   return
 $("#second").hide();
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 3px solid black">

</div>
<div id="second" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 3px solid black; display: none">

</div>
```